# How to get the values of a specific hyperlink in php and if click, send to another page the session of that named link

Tags: php, session

**view.php**

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM insgroup WHERE insID = '".$_SESSION['insID']."' ") or die ("Error selecting group from sessions:".mysqli_error($conn));

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";


echo "<tr><th>Group ID</th><th>Group Name</th><th>Group Description</th><th>Group Subject</th><th>Group Department</th><th>Group Owner</th><th>Group Section</th><th>Group Year Level</th></tr>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  // set up a row for each record
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['groupid'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a class='group-name' name='group-home-redirect' href='grouphome.php'  >" . $row['groupname'] . "</a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['groupdesc'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['groupsubject'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['groupdept'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['groupowner'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['groupsection'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['groupyearlevel'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a name='delete-grp-btn' href='editgroup.php?id=" . $row['groupid'] . "'>Edit Group</a></td>";
  echo "<td><a href='deletegroup.php?id=" . $row['groupid'] . "'>Delete Group</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table><br><br><NOSCRIPT><FONT COLOR='#FF0000'><BR>Javascript is required to access this area. Yours seems to be disabled.</FONT></NOSCRIPT> ";

if($result === FALSE){
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No rows for instructor' ".$_SESSION['insfname']." .".$_SESSION['inslname']." 'to be displayed.');</script>";      
}
```

The link is named "group-home-redirect". When I create a group, i wanted to be shown in the view table, and if the user click the group name, automatically the values of that group in the database will be called using session perhaps. God i really dont know,

Comment: what? Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? its a bit confusing.

Comment: what do you mean by this: _"if the user click the group name, automatically the values of that group in the database will be called"_ ?

Comment: @CodeGodie, sorry for confusing a little bit, i just want to create a link, for a specific group name in a view table, if the user clicks the href link, automatically, those row table values of that "group" will be send to another page and post the information in the grouphome.php.

Comment: in that case then I agree with @Julio's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood what you want...

you could pass the group ID in the href...

something like:

```
echo "<td><a class='group-name' name='group-home-redirect' href='grouphome.php?group=" . $row['groupid'] . "'  >" . $row['groupname'] . "</a></td>"
```

Then on your grouphome.php you would look for $_GET['group'] and use it's value to get all you want from the tables...

Just as you are already doing on

```
echo "<td><a href='deletegroup.php?id=" . $row['groupid'] . "'>Delete Group</a></td>";
```

Are you planning to keep code and presentation in the same file like this?

Comment: your a guardian angel! thank you it works, but another question, my project has two user level, one is the instructor, the other one is the student, and the creator of groups is the instrctor, my question is, is the student can see those values of the group?

Comment: @ProgrammerX what do you mean? clarify.

Comment: Well... you can decide what to show to your users...
Let's say, when the user login you check if he/she is a student or a teacher.
then you imediately set a session variable $_SESSION['is_teatcher'], for isntance.
Then on each page you check

    IF($_SESSION[' is_teatcher]){
    .... show this
    }
    ELSE{
    .... show that
    }

But... I would sugest you to research some template engine like smarty.net
so you can keep code and html separated and make your life easier...

Comment: Okaay. thank you for your comments guys. I will now continue now my project, actually, it is my thesis. thank you again!.